# Unit testing c# code in a ScriptSharp project

Tags: c#, nunit, script#

Im using ScriptSharp to create a RIA app.
Works nice besides some oddities.

However finding and fixing problems using Firebug isn't really convinient.

Since scriptsharp also delivers a Dll I was hoping to use a separate testproject using Nunit to test some parts of my code.

Issue that arises is that the generated dll references mscorlib 0.7 resulting in conflict with mscorlib 4 in the test project.

A simple solution is to create a second plain C# project and copy codefiles around. But maintaining 2 projects with the same code base...

Curious if there is another way to do this. Anybody?

EDIT:
Solution as proposed by Christian Dalager works.

Small thing is that ScriptSharp has redefined System.Diagnostics in mscorlib. No more Debug.Assert/Writeline. But there is almost no more need for it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using [assembly binding redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx)

You would put something like this in the app.config on your testproject.
Havent tested this particular configuration, so you will need to adjust it.

```xml
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v1.0.3705">
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="mscorlib" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.7.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
     </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: It seems to do the trick! Resharper isn't aware of it and keeps complaining but that's a minor issue. Is there also a way to redirect namespaces in a same way?

Comment: I think you need to code your way out of that one.. Can't you just tell resharper to ignore that one somehow?

Comment: Resharper is easy to shut up.

Comment: @lboshuizen, if you think this answer actually answered your question, you should accept it by clicking on the green tick mark.