# "Inject" an operator into an existing type

Tags: c#, script#, system.reflection

Scriptsharp uses mscorlib 0.7.0.0 which has an implicit operator System.Number on an int32. I understand the reason why it's there although I imagine that the compiler can handle the conversion in another way.

Now I can't use the generated scriptsharp .Dll in an other project (ex unit testing) that uses the standard .Net mscorlib. > 3.0.

```
> Method not found System.Int32._opImplicit(int32).
```

Is there a way to "inject" that operator through reflection?

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104853/unit-testing-c-sharp-code-in-a-scriptsharp-project) brought me a bug step further, but this one....

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify types that are already loaded into an appdomain.

The only way I think you could do this is to modify mscorlib.dll and then use that modified version. The [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) library allows you to do exactly that. Although it requires you to deal with CIL.

Comment: Seems clear to me, I already came to that conclusion but perhaps I overlooked something