# Using Script# code with string operations in standart C# .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, string, script#

I added reference of Script# to my standart console application. After that I was trying to invoke some method from there but was getting the following error:

[image: MissingMethodException]

I suppose it happened on the following line:

```
string[] lines = s.Split(';');
```

My assumption is that usual **mscorlib** library has not method `public string[] Split(char separator)`, but has `public string[] Split(params char[] separator)`

Is it possible to write valid code with such string operations both for a Script# project and for a standart C# .NET project? Due to this problem I have to write duplicate code for both projects with minimal difference.

**P.S.** I tried to use assemblty binding redirects, as discussed in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8104853/1046374) question, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!

My sequence of actions:

1. Create `Split` method of string splitting in any Script# class.
2. Define conditional compilation symbol **DOTNET** in your .NET project.
3. **Add As Link** file with `Split` method from Script# to .NET project and also add as link another necessary dependent files.

```cs
public static string[] Split(string str, string separator)
{
    string[] result;
#if DOTNET
    result = str.Split(new string[] { separator }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
#else
    result = str.Split(separator);
#endif
    return result;
}
```

After that appropriate code will be selected dependent on DOTNET symbol, which defined only in .NET project. Other similar methods, not only with strings, can be rewritten in the same way.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**
The only solution to me seems to be the extension methods. You can define extension method `Split` on top of Script#'s String type similar to the standard .NET `String.Split`, i.e. accepting `params char[]`. And only then you can use the same code.

```
string[] lines = s.Split(new char[] { ';' });
```

Alternatively, define extension on top of standard String type, in case Script# is strict on extensions. But I think should not be a problem since extension method is just a static method.

**OLD ANSWER:** After realizing that Script# does not accept `params char[]`, below answer became incorrect:

You are invoking `s.Split` by passing `char` to it. However, this method accepts `params char[]`. Although C# compiler allows you to pass `char` to `Split`, it later compiles it into passing `char[]`. So, if you want to have the same code working for both Script# and C#, change your code to the following way:

```
string[] lines = s.Split(new char[] { ';' });
```

This will work for both Script# and C#.

Comment: Unfortunately you are wrong: Script# does not have `public string[] Split(char[] separator)` method signature because of it built on own **mscorlib** without such method signature.

Comment: You mean Script# has method accepting just char? please provide the method signature provided by Script#. I assumed it accepts params char[].

Comment: Not only char but other signatures too, excluding char array. You could see it on [github](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/blob/master/src/Core/CoreLib/String.cs).

Comment: You're right. I guess Script#'s author wanted to have a control over C#-to-JS compilation. I just updated my answer. I hope this time it will be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, extension methods does not work in Script# environment (An following compiler error occurs: Feature 'extension method' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification). Extension method for standart String type in .NET project also does not helps (In this case the same runtime error with missing method occurs).

Comment: Ah, sorry. Probably ISO-2 specification of C# is too old for this stuff.